# TASM code gives error in YASM: instruction expected after label

Tags: assembly, tasm, yasm

I have code I made for TASM, and to my knowledge YASM is compatible with that, so IDK why I get these errors:

> ```
> 91.asm:3: error: instruction expected after label
> 91.asm:4: error: instruction expected after label
> 91.asm:27: error: instruction expected after label
> ```

for this code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 21h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------
CODESEG
global start
start:
; --------------------------
; Your code here
; --------------------------
    mov cx, 21
    mov ax, 1000h
    cmp cx, 0
    je myExit
addStack:
    push ax
    inc ax
    loop addStack
myExit:
exit:
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Answer (score 1):

YASM is *not* compatible with TASM, not to my knowledge.  It's compatible with **N**ASM which uses totally different directives.  (And different meaning for `mov reg, label` - in NASM/YASM it's a mov-immediate of the address, unlike TASM/MASM where it's a load.)

Something on a line by itself without a `:` can be a label (and this is what YASM assumes if it's not recognized as an instruction mnemonic).

But if it's followed by something else that's also not understood as an instruction (like `small` in `MODEL small`), that's a syntax error.

Use NASM / YASM syntax for YASM.

Comment: do you know a compatible assembler with TASM that can run on Linux, or make regular bin files?

Comment: @sefsf: Possibly JWASM (I think it's at least mostly MASM compatible), but it's not like Linux can *run* DOS `.com` flat-binary executables natively.  Or you could just port your code to YASM; flat binaries are pretty simple so it's not like you'll need a lot of directives.  (IMO NASM/YASM syntax for actual instructions is the best designed out of all of MASM, AT&T, or other major options.)